# Flash embed breaks animation-flow (!?)

Tags: jquery, flash, integration

I made a little animation for a client. Its a repeating movement of  a cat. The flash-file works great and shows an endless animation without interruptions. But after I integrated that animation, it plays the animation wrong. It sticks on some point. Heres the code and the link:

The (embeded) animation http://davidgoltz.com/2011/wp-content/themes/davidgoltz/images/katze.swf

http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/contact/ (after you click on the fish)

The code: http://pastebin.com/hMKW5Mtj

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I put it up about 10 minutes ago and it is still running.

Comment: And does the cat has some itches while it animates?

Comment: It's working nice and smooth for me on Chome 13 and FireFox 5.0 under Windows 7 Pro x64.

Comment: Than it seems to be a Mac-problem because I'm running chrome on Mac and the animation is broken after embedding (the original file runs smoothly as well) on http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/contact/ (after you click on the fish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you looping the animation? Sometimes you have to restart the animation by hand by writing code that detects when the animation has reached it final frame and then goto and play frame 1.

I have seen this before myself when using embedded swfs where restarting the playback head using timeline code with an embedded swf doesnt work.